# assembly code on Windows 8 x64

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm new to hardware near programming with assembly code. So I read a book about it and found this sample code for the NASM assembler:

```
segment .text                               ;code segment
global main                                 ;must be declared for linker
main:                                       ;tell linker entry point
mov edx,len                                 ;message length
mov ecx,msg                                 ;message to write
mov ebx,1                                   ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4                                   ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80                                    ;call kernel
mov eax,1                                   ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80                                    ;call kernel

segment .data                               ;data segment
msg db 'Hello, world!',0xa                  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg                             ;length of our dear string
```

So I compiled it with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 helloworld.asm
ld -s -o helloworld.exe helloworld.o
```

The assembler has no problem to assemble it and gives no errors, but the program crashes instantly. I read about different assembly-languages, but the point is that the assembly-code varies with different compilers not with different operating systems, so where is my mistake?

Comment: Why do you assume that the problem is the OS. Maybe it would have crashed on the same machine if running Windows 7. Did you test that scenario? If it's not the OS, that leaves the machine.

Comment: For any x64 OS I'd try first `mov rcx, msg` (And I also doubt Win 8 uses linux style system calls. Windows 7 didn't.)

Comment: [Win8 does not seem to use INT for syscalls](http://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER).

Comment: On windows, you call ExitProcess from system32.dll to quit. System calls are very OS-specific.

Comment: You're trying to perform Linux system calls in Windows, which isn't going to work. Use WinAPI functions like `WriteConsole` and `ExitProcess` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The code that you're showing is x86_32 linux code.
You can tell, because it uses `int` calls which Windows does not and this line:

```
nasm -f elf64 helloworld.asm
```

Produces output in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linking_Format) format, which is a linux executable.
Windows uses PE *(portable executable)* which is the MS [EEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish) variant of [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF).

x64 code uses `RAX`, `RBX` ...., although the 32-bit variant registers `EAX` etc also feature heavily.

Before you can learn how to write assembly.
You need to know the ABI (calling conventions) and the API of a system.

For the ABI have a look at: [Calling Conventions - PDF](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)

If you want to know how to do API calls in Windows, write a simple C program that does the job and then get a disassembler and look at the x86 code.
For more info on the API calls have a look at MSDN, specifically:

[Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)
[Windows Console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[ExitProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assemble your executable on PE format and change the `int 0x80` to a `call ExecuteInterrupt128`.
You can give it a same name. You can learn how to write a PE executable on NASM.
Just go to the homepage of Stack Overflow.

The ExecuteInterrupt128 function must look like this:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
cmp eax, byte +1
je SleepSystem
cmp eax, byte +4
je PrintString
...
SleepSystem:
push byte -1
call Sleep
leave
ret
PrintString:
push -11
call GetStdHandle
push byte +0
push byte +6
lea esi, [ebp-4]
push edx
push ecx
push eax
call WriteConsoleA
leave
ret
```

Or try this commands:

```
    nasm -f win32 -o executable.o executable.asm
    ld -o executable.exe executable.o
```